# I want to print user's ID from database on one modal

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to print user's ID from data on one modal.I did everything, I get ID in execute method I put that ID in jsonArray and print it on console but now didn't get that ID in ajax's result .when I put result inside alert to check whether i am getting it or not it throws null data.here is my code,

//code of ajax

```
function printUCID()
{
    //alert("hi");
    $.ajax({
        url : "registerclient",

        contentType: "application/json",
        cache : false,
        success : function(result) {

            alert(result[0]);
            /*cid=result;*/
            }
       }); 

}
```

here is my execute method

```
public String execute() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException, JSONException {
        //System.out.println(email);
        RegisterDao RDAO = new RegisterDao();

        //System.out.println("country " + country);
        String i = RegisterDao.save(this);
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();


        response.setContentType("application/json"); 
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        System.out.println("########"+i);
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        //jobj.put("result",i);

        //String data = jobj.getString("result");
        //System.out.println("data"+data);
        JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray1.put(i);

        out.print(i);
        System.out.println("jsonArray1"+jsonArray1);

        if (i.length() > 0) {



    }
```

i get data in out.print()
but now stuck here please help me out.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the JSON array from the execute function.

Comment: yeah..I return JSON array from execute function but still not getting it in result of ajax.if possible can u please guide me by doing some code.

Comment: You can inspect the the result object from the browser console and see what it contains. In chrome it is Ctrl+Shift+j

Comment: just use console.log(result) and run it in the browser and inspect.

Comment: ok...I'll try....but one more thing is I got that ID even on console window also.and it's very frustrating for me that I can see it over console but not getting it in result.